# How can i exit from custom ContentDialog

Tags: c#, uwp

**Situation:** I have a custom Contentdialog with two custom buttons.

**Problem:** I can't find a way to close the custom ContentDialog when I click on one of my buttons.
I have a look at the Microsoft document and other Youtube channels, but unfortunately, I didn't find it.

Thanks for the helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to hide the ContentDialog using `Hide();`.